# jQuery bluimp Fileupload - Keep Select Images Rows After Uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have been using http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ for my rails application. The current behaviour of this plugin is after image is uploaded it removes the row of selected image and show different row to download the image uploaded.

I want to keep selected images table, block the page with preloader image and redirect after all images uploaded. I manage to show preloader, block the page and redirect but don't know how to prevent plugin from removing selected images.

Would anyone please help me to override this behaviour so plugin doesn't remove the row of selected image even after image is uploaded.

Thanks, Amit Patel

Answer (score 0):

I did a trick. I modified download file row template to match the file upload row template. After file is uploaded it now shows newly created thumnail. So looks like image is still there.